# Tray application working as proxy - Asyncronous operations

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-web-api, backgroundworker

I have a Tray application that work as proxy to a set of windows forms applications, so that all comunication to the main server WebApi is handled trough it.

Meanwhile I have a requirement for the Tray application to do a paralel job, which is basically calling the main server WebApi to refresh some local files.

This job should be run every X minutes, and I am not sure if a background worker is a good choice here. Basically I don't want the Tray application to be stuck on that side process, so that it still respond as proxy to the other apps.

Is the `backgroudworker` the correct choice here?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

On .NET 3.5 using a BackgroundWorker is the usual way of processing data in seperate threads. On .NET 4.0+ Tasks are the new and recommended way of doing these operations ( with parallel ).